# Game.getInstance().getPlayerKills() devuelve un hashmap e int, solo quiero obtener el integer como lo separo?

Tags: java

Parte del codigo que quiero separar

```
if (GameState.INGAME == 0) {
                    show.add("&eKills&7:&c " + Game.getInstance().getPlayerKills());
   }
```

[image: valor]

Comment: Hola Another Developer, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son.  

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. Sería de gran ayuda que nos mostraras el método **getPlayerKills()**.

Comment: Solo devuelve un HashMap<UUID, Integer>, no veo el Integer. Agrega más informacion.

Comment: `HashMap<UUID, Integer>` es un diccionario que asocia un `Integer` a un `UUID`. Para obtener un `Integer` debes usar la función `get` el diccionario pasando su `UUID` asociado. Para más información consulta [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Si tienes dificultades entendiendo, repasa tus conocimientos de programación o busca  un tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

`UUID` es la abreviatura de "Universally Unique Identifier" y se refiere a un identificador único y estandarizado que se utiliza en diferentes contextos, como por ejemplo, en sistemas distribuidos, bases de datos, aplicaciones web, entre otros.

Necesitas crear un objeto UUID a partir de la cadena de caracteres que estás utilizando como clave en el mapa. Puedes hacerlo llamando al método estático `UUID.fromString()` y pasando la cadena como argumento.

```
Map<UUID, Integer> numeros = new HashMap<>();

    UUID uuid1 = UUID.fromString("734ded40-83ac-4a00-bdf6-477d756f519c");
    UUID uuid2 = UUID.fromString("76ffed11-da80-4961-b0d9-a576eeefc91d");

    numeros.put(uuid1, 1);
    numeros.put(uuid2, 2);

    int numero = numeros.get(uuid1);
    System.out.println("numero = " + numero);

    //Result = 1;

    Collection<Integer> valores =numeros.values();
    for(var v : valores){
        System.out.println("v = " + v);
    }

    //Resul 1, 2
```

Recreando lo que comentas te dejo un ejemplo que te puede servir como guia

Saludos...

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el valor entero de tu HashMap (`HashMap<UUID, Integer>`), es necesario  conocer el identificador del usuario (`UUID`= y usar la función [**get()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) para obtener su valor respectivo.

Este es un ejemplo:

```
    HashMap<UUID, Integer> players = new HashMap<>();
    UUID myUUID1 = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes("8fbf09f7-c108-44b3-bf15-1a73489ed759".getBytes());
    UUID myUUID2 = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes("c1c7a8ed-e44d-49a1-8dce-af5068d25426".getBytes());
    UUID myUUID3 = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes("91582dcf-7f77-4d22-a27a-8b556b3754c4".getBytes());

    players.put(myUUID1 , 122);
    players.put(myUUID2 , 220);
    players.put(myUUID3 , 305);
    System.out.println(players);

    //* Obtiene el valor correspondiente a "c1c7a8ed-e44d-49a1-8dce-af5068d25426" que sería 220
    System.out.println(players.get(myUUID2));
```

por lo tanto realizarías algo similar a

```
int playerKills = Game.getInstance().getPlayerKills().get(Usuario_UUID);
```